# Load the data from an Excel File and load into a Temp Table

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to load an Excel file into a Temp table so that I can perform some manipulations in the Temp Table.

I'am using the following statement to open the excel file. But now I need to load it into a temp table.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\b1.xlsx; hdr=yes',
                'SELECT * FROM [Co Contact$]') AS A;
```

What Iam trying to is some thing like this

```
select top 0 *
into #mytemptable
from A
```

I need to do it with out declaring the Temp Table without specifying the names of the columns in the excel file. (Because the excel file may contain nearly 100 columns)

Is it possible ?

Comment: what happens when you try ?

Comment: Thanks..I get message "Invalid object name 'A'" while trying to insert into the TempTable. I think "A" loses its scope before executing the second statement .

Comment: Why not import data from excell directly into SQL server DB, then querry DB like mad all you like

Comment: Is SELECT A.* INTO #mytemptable FROM OPENROWSET(ExcelInfo) not allowed?

Comment: @  Kprof thanks ..yes it is and its working :)

Comment: @Ananth Your welcome; I had to add permissions on mine in order to do it, which is why I asked :).  Glad to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your first statement works, to put it into a temp table you need to do this:

```
SELECT A.*
INTO #MyTempTable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\b1.xlsx; hdr=yes',
                'SELECT * FROM [Co Contact$]') AS A;
```

Then you can play with #mytemptable

```
Select * From #mytemptable;
```